# Importing `express` library takes hundreds of milliseconds. Is there a way to speed up this process?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am running NodeJS & Express in serverless setup. When the serverless instance is up and running, everything is good and served well. However, when the serverless instance has to serve a request with a cold start after minutes of inactivity, it actually takes a while (around ~300ms latency addition) to import `express` library, while it takes only few milliseconds or tens of milliseconds to import other library files.

Below is an example of a cold start which 300ms had to be added to import express file..

```
...
2020-01-17 00:33:07.762 PST Launching...
2020-01-17 00:33:07.787 PST{level: 30, msg: Pino logger initialized, time: 1579249987787, v: 1}
2020-01-17 00:33:07.802 PST{level: 30, msg: Imported BodyParser, time: 1579249987802, v: 1}
2020-01-17 00:33:08.103 PST{level: 30, msg: Imported Express, time: 1579249988103, v: 1} // <----Took 300ms
2020-01-17 00:33:08.108 PST{level: 30, msg: Imported AsyncHandler, time: 1579249988108, v: 1}
2020-01-17 00:33:08.120 PST{level: 30, msg: Imported Express Pino Logger, time: 1579249988119, v: 1}
2020-01-17 00:33:08.166 PST{level: 30, msg: Imported Service library, time: 1579249988166, v: 1}
...
```

Below is a actual server snippet.

```js
...
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
log.info("Imported BodyParser");
import express from "express";
log.info("Imported Express");
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
log.info("Imported AsyncHandler");
...
```

I was wondering if there is a way to speed up express import (load it asynchronously? - I use typescript with es2019), or if there is a good alternative or lighter version of express. I primarily use routing, middleware, and bodyparser features in `express`, and nothing else.

Comment: Well, nodejs and Express are not really designed for cold start upon incoming request.  Normally, the server would start once and then just be waiting for incoming requests and this would not be an issue.  You can examine the dependencies of Express and/or profile the loading if you want to see what's taking time.  Not something most of us ever care about as a few hundred ms when the server starts is not a big deal for most of us.  Perhaps a better solution is to not use a serverless infrastructure for a node.js server or pick a system designed for that type of infrastructure.

Comment: `npm view express` will show you all the dependent modules that Express is loading.  I'm seeing 30 module depedencies.  `npm view express dependencies` will show the structure of those dependencies (what pulls in what).

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for "pick a system designed for that type of infrastructure" ?

Comment: What hosting provider?

Comment: I use Google Cloud Run with packaged Docker image of nodejs server. But since I use Docker, any programming languages that you recommend should work as long as they have short cold start time.

Comment: I'm no expert here, but in what I've read about serverless design, things are way more efficient if you use one of the cloud platforms serverless designs rather than start up a whole server image every time an incoming http request arrives. You can read about the Google Cloud Functions interface [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/).  For Amazon, it's AWS Lambda.

Comment: Consider using [this](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack) library to bundle NodeJS dependencies and perform tree shaking.